# Sub-select SUM of columns WHERE x=y

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a statement along the lines of:

```
SELECT
    SUM(claims.sanctioned_resultant) AS 'Resultant',
    SUM(claims.sanctioned_flooring) AS 'Flooring',
    SUM(claims.sanctioned_contents) AS 'Furniture',
```

etc, and I need to include a "WHERE" in this somehow. Along the lines of:

```
SUM(claims.sanctioned_resultant WHERE claims.a_column = 1)
```

Obviously this doesn't work, since SUM just.. sums. I currently have a whole other query with the `WHERE claims_a_column = 1` clause, then later combine the results. The "WHERE" condition cannot be added to this query, as the majority of results won't be selected by it.

I've looked into CASE WHEN, and sub-selects, but can't figure out the actual syntax.

Full query, in case it helps:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(users.user_first_name,IF((users.user_surname<>''),CONCAT(' ',users.user_surname),'')) as 'Surveyor',
    SUM(claims.sanctioned_roof + claims.sanctioned_building + claims.sanctioned_internal + claims.sanctioned_resultant + claims.sanctioned_flooring + claims.sanctioned_contents) AS 'Overall', 
    SUM(claims.sanctioned_roof) AS 'Roofing',
    SUM(claims.sanctioned_building + claims.sanctioned_internal) AS 'Building',
    SUM(claims.sanctioned_resultant) AS 'Resultant',
    SUM(claims.sanctioned_flooring) AS 'Flooring',
    SUM(claims.sanctioned_contents) AS 'Furniture',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN claims.claimed_amount > 0 THEN 1 END) AS 'OverallCount',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN (claims.claimed_amount > 0 AND claims.peril_id IN (" . implode(',', $WRPPerils) . ")) THEN 1 END) AS 'WRPCount',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN claims.claimed_roof > 0 THEN 1 END) AS 'RoofingCount',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN (claims.claimed_building > 0) OR (claims.sanctioned_internal > 0) THEN 1 END) AS 'BuildingCount',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN claims.claimed_resultant > 0 THEN 1 END) AS 'ResultantCount',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN claims.claimed_flooring > 0 THEN 1 END) AS 'FlooringCount',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN claims.claimed_contents > 0 THEN 1 END) AS 'FurnitureCount',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN claims.claimed_amount > 0 AND claims.letter_of_findings = 'Y' THEN 1 END) AS 'LOFCount'
FROM 
    claims claims 
    INNER JOIN users users ON claims.surveyor_id = users.user_id
    INNER JOIN insurers insurers on claims.insurer_id = insurers.insurer_id
WHERE
    (claims.claim_type <> " . $conn->qstr(TYPE_DESKTOP) . ") AND
    (claims.claim_type <> " . $conn->qstr(TYPE_AUDIT) . ") AND
    (claims.claim_cancelled_id <= 0) AND
    (claims.date_completed BETWEEN '" . $start_date . " 00:00:00' AND '" . $end_date . " 23:59:59') AND
    (claims.overturn_confirmed = 'N' OR claims.overturn_confirmed IS NULL)
GROUP BY surveyor_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do what you want will be using a CASE statement within the SUM function itself, like this:

`SUM(CASE WHEN claims.a_column = 1 THEN claims.sanctioned_resultant ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: @Rahul The value that OP wants to sum is from another column. The use of a_column is just for a condition.